# Uninstall all Formulae and dependencies - Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, uninstallation

I use the packet manager `Homebrew` to install apps. But in the last time I install some formulae too and after tipping `brew list` it turns out that I install not only formulaes but also its dependencies. So I decided to uninstall them (all Formulae and its dependencies) because I do not need them anymore. I want to keep all `casks`. How can I do that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming; try https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew provides [an uninstall script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh).

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"`

Comment: Hi @chenrui thanks for the help. This script is for uninstall Homebrew completely but I want to keep all casks that I uninstalled and only delete all Formulae and its dependencies.

Comment: try this, `brew remove --force $(brew list --formula)`